# kafka-topics.sh - I am getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty client certificate chain"

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and trying to setup an SSL-enabled Kafka.

To provide a reproducible scenario, I created the truststore/keystore using this script: https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/44218#issuecomment-1677577552

I then converted the 2 stores to pkcs12 format (still getting same error as with JKS type)

My kafka-topics command:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server "kafka:9092" --command-config=kafka-ssl.properties --list
```

My kafka-ssl.properties file:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.type=PKCS12
ssl.truststore.location=kafka.keystore.p12
ssl.truststore.password=a1234141aadfafwg
enable.ssl.certificate.verification=false
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

From the kafka-topics.sh debug logs I believe these lines pinpoint the problem:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.896 EEST|SSLCipher.java:1870|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.906 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.908 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.908 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.909 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.910 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.913 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.914 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.915 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ed25519
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.916 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.917 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ed448
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.918 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.919 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.920 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.921 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.922 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.923 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.924 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.924 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.925 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.926 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.936 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.938 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.938 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.939 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.940 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.941 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.943 EEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.944 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.945 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1094|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.946 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1106|No available client authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.947 EEST|CertificateMessage.java:1140|Produced client Certificate message (
"Certificate": {
  "certificate_request_context": "",
  "certificate_list": [  
]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.952 EEST|CertificateVerify.java:1093|No X.509 credentials negotiated for CertificateVerify
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E0|kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1|2023-10-17 13:20:45.956 EEST|Finished.java:687|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 2A C0 7A 3E B1 71 45 CD   75 EC 87 4B FE 4D E8 FC  *.z>.qE.u..K.M..
    0010: 5F F2 2C CD DE 71 2C F9   40 45 18 39 BC ED 96 C5  _.,..q,.@E.9....
    0020: 23 7D 99 EA 0B FD 4E 36   8B BA C5 08 90 97 F8 34  #.....N6.......4
  }'}
)
```

On Kafka server it just says `Empty client certificate chain`:

```
[2023-10-17 13:20:45,993] DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=192.168.4.121:9092-192.168.4.121:54490-0 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/192.168.4.121:9092 remote=/192.168.4.121:54490], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@6f6cd427, interestOps=1, readyOps=0] SSL Handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty client certificate chain
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
....
....
....
[2023-10-17 13:20:46,012] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /192.168.4.121 (channelId=192.168.4.121:9092-192.168.4.121:54490-0) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: The error says that the Kafka client is not presenting a client certificate during the SSL handshake. If you want to configure an authetification with SSL, you need to add certificates to both client and server. Did you add certificate in kafka client ?

Comment: @SaraM. plz see my answer below, i had to add a section for `ssl.keystore`, (which totally makes sense for mTLS setup). pretty embarrassing mistake now that i look back, but happens when introduced to new software :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that my `kafka-ssl.properties` was not including keystore configuration (via ssl.keystore.xxx variables):

correct `client-ssl.properties` example from https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html for mTLS config:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka1:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have configured Broker with 2-way SSL and Client is not sending any certificate to authenticate itself.

[This link may provide additional info on how to setup mTLS between the producer client and the kafka broker](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html)

Comment: thank you, trying several things with a colleague accidentally made me realize what i was missing, which is also included in your link.